# fetch results from sqlite database

Tags: javascript, sql, sqlite

i want to get the location from specific user and when i run this code it gets me error ' Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'location' of undefined '
and i dont know how i can fixed.
this is the code :

```
db.transaction(function(tx){
     tx.executeSql("SELECT location FROM users WHERE username='"+username+"'",[], success ); 
});

function success(tx,results){
     var city = results.rows.item[0].location;
}
```

Comment: Please make the example code a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using square brackets instead of parentheses when you call item on results.rows.

Comment: No problem. Please select this as the answer and have a good day! :-)